# Как сделать топ пользователей с выводом позиции текущего пользователя

Tags: laravel

нужно реализовать ТОП 100 пользователей по столбцу EXP и если текущий пользователь не входит в топ, то отдельно ниже вывести место текущего пользователя
Как вывести ТОП 100 это понятно:

```
$top = User::orderBy('exp', 'DESC')->select('name', 'exp')->limit(100)->get();
```

И если мы знаем место текущего пользователя, то можно проверить, оно больше 100 или меньше, если больше, то мы выводим текущего пользователя с его местом под ТОП 100, если меньше, то в `foreach` перебираем полученный список, находим пользователя и выделяем его.

Проблема заключается в том, что я не понимаю как высчитать место текущего пользователя
В принципе можно добавить новый столбец `place` в таблицу `users` и например раз в час перебирать всех пользователей(отсортировать по exp desc) и сохранять текущую позицию в поле `place`
Но что делать если пользователей будет свыше 1мл, тогда перебрать всех пользователей и у каждого изменить `place` будет слишком затратно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно завернуть вот такой запрос (основано на [SQL Find Position in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310080/sql-find-position-in-table)):

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
      id, 
      name, 
      exp, 
      (@rownum := @rownum + 1) UserRank 
    FROM users, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t 
    ORDER BY exp DESC
    ) tt
WHERE tt.id = 4
```

Ну или просто посчитать количество пользователей, которые выше (у которых экспы больше, чем у текущего пользователя):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM users
WHERE exp >= 100500
ORDER BY exp DESC
```

Если нужно диапазон позиции (если у многих экспа совпадает), то предыдущий запрос выполняем дважды с `>` и `>=`.